# How to find and copy the content of sub directories in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have a root folder that has a structure as

```
root
    A 
    |-30
       |-a.txt
       |-b.txt 
    |-90
       |-a.txt
       |-b.txt  
    B
    |-60
       |-a.txt
       |-b.txt  
    C
    |-200
       |-a.txt
       |-b.txt  
    |-300 
       |-a.txt
       |-b.txt
```

I want to find all subfolders (A,B,C,D) such that the subfolder of the subfolder (likes 30,90,...) smaller than **60**. Then copy all file with the name is `a.txt` in the subfolder to another directory. and the output likes

```
root_filter
    A 
    |-30
       |-a.txt
    B
    |-60
       |-a.txt
```

I am using python but I cannot obtain the result

```
dataroot = './root'
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(dataroot):
    print (dir,os.path.isdir(dir))
```

Comment: why check dir? it  is always a dir ... you do not check any files name, you convert nothing to a number, ...,  you do not copy at all, you do not do what you need to achieve your task. What ist your specific problem? As is we would need to code all for you... and we generally do not do this. Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet and [edit] your code to a specific problem we _can_ answer.

Comment: Problem is I cannot find the sub folder likes A and 30. How to find it?

Comment: Read the documentation of os.walk - `dirs` is a list of subdirectories of dataroot - and  it steps into all dirs in it recursivly ... `dir` holds the dir you are currently watching at - thats why it is normally called root. dirs and files are lists - print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you just need to run a few checks on where you are, before copying the file. This can be accomplished with a number of clauses in a simple `if` statement inside the `for` loop:

```
import shutil
import os

dataroot = './root'
target_dir = './some_other_dir'
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(dataroot):
    # First, we want to check if we're at the right level of directory
    #   we can do this by counting the number of '/' in the name of the directory
    #   (the distance from where we started). For ./root/A/30 there should be 
    #   3 instances of the character '/'
    # Then, we want to ensure that the folder is numbered 60 or less.
    #   to do this, we isolate the name of *this* folder, cast it to an int,
    #   and then check its value
    # Finally, we check if 'a.txt' is in the directory
    if dir.count('/') == 3 and int(dir[dir.rindex('/')+1:]) <= 60 and 'a.txt' in files:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(dir, 'a.txt'), target_dir)
```

You'll need to work something up to name the files when you copy them to `target_dir`, so they don't overwrite each other. That depends on your use case.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks. Can we automatically count the number of `/`. For example if the root is `/home/hee/data/root' then it must be change the number

Comment: You could maybe replace `3` with `(dataroot.count('/') + 2)`, since you want 2 levels down from your root directory. But in general `os.walk()` works with relative directories - if you put in `'./root'` then it'll spit out directories that start with `./root/...`.

Comment: As another sidenote, this code may not work on windows since windows uses backslashes instead. In that case you could change `'/'` to `os.sep`, which stores the "separator character" used by the OS you're currently running on

Comment: Thanks. I got the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: `

Comment: I think the line `int(dir[dir.index('/')+1:])`. The full error is ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: root/A/30

Comment: oh, whoops. Should be using `rindex()` to get the *last* index of the character instead of `index()` to get the first index. I'll change my solution.